# Controlling one FCU with two thermostats

Tags: hvac, thermostat, air-conditioning

I have a chilled water fan coil unit that will feed two areas, living and the bedroom.

I want to control the FCU with two thermostats, one in the living and one in the bedroom, (preferably) in a master / slave arrangement.

The FCU fan speed and modulating of the chilled water valve actuator will be based on the average temperature detected by both thermostats.

The setpoint will be taken from the last entered location, meaning if I'm in the living and go to the bedroom and change the setpoint from there, THAT will be the one that the FCU will be controlled based on.

I know that this can be achieved with a DDC controller, but the catch is, that I don't want to pay for that.

**Are there any master / slave thermostats / solutions in the market for this? (which can achieve this without a separate controller)**

Thanks in advance!